# Visual Studio 2017 csproj .NET Core build - views not being copied correctly

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a project running in .NET Core and I am using VS2017 as IDE.

When I build my project through Visual Studio 2017 it does not automatically add the Views folder and the wwwroot folder to the output in `[projectRoot]/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/win10-x64`(`BuildDir`). This means that if I try to run my website directly from the `.exe file` created in the bin folder, I get an error with the missing `views` and `wwwroot`. If I manually copy these folders to the `BuildDir` then the views load correctly.

This I can setup in my .csproj file with the following:

```
<Content Update="Views\**">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

And then the `Views` work but now my layout file is not being compiled so I get the following:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - FirstAgenda</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/overwrite.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/overwrite.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
```

This means that my root folder is not being targeted correctly. And also kinda tells me that just copying the files to the output directory is incorrect.

All of the above is working if I do a publish of my application (also without the addition to the .csproj file). I just have a project runner that I would like to be able to point to the Debug version of my websites executable file, because it is very easy to forget to do a publish compared to just building the project with VS2017.

I just don't know where to go from this and any help will be appreciated?

**EDIT:**

Added the stripped down version of csproj (which does not work):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="1.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.EntityFramework" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OctoPack" Version="3.5.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet">
      <Version>1.1.0-preview4-final</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools">
      <Version>1.0.0-msbuild1-final</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools">
      <Version>1.0.0-msbuild1-final</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\[OWNPROJECT]" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\[OWNPROJECT1]" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Also tried creating a new project with `dotnet new mvc`

And it is also not working.

My dotnet core cli version is [1.0.1].

**EDIT:**

I followed the steps you outlined. I also tried to create a new project with `dotnet new mvc` and followed your steps. Both gave me the same errors. It was unable to find the `appsettings.json`. If I then add a `propertygroup` to the .csproj. That tells msbuild to copy appsettings.json and web.config to the output

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="appsettings.json;web.config">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I can then start the program through the exe, but when I access the index, then when I try to access one of the views it gives me:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
    An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
    System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
  /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
  /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

**UPDATE:**

Shaun Lutins answer seems to be working for me. Both with build and publish options. Only problem was that I was getting an error:

`Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default.`

But it was resolved by changing the following:

```
<ItemGroup>                                                                            
   <Content Include="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
   <Content Include="Views\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
   <Content Include="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to

```
<ItemGroup>                                                                            
   <Content Update="appsettings.json;web.config" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
   <Content Update="Views\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
   <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to one that lets us run the output EXE from *any* location. Let me know please whether it works for you or not.

Comment: In your update, you are getting the error because you are not using `<EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>` which is included in Shaun's example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The challenge as I have interpreted it is **to run `dotnet build` and be able to execute the compiled EXE from anywhere.** The answer requires two steps:

1. copy required content to the bin, and
2. set the ContentRoot and WebRoot relative to the bin.

First, modify the csproj to copy required content to the bin. Out of the box, `dotnet build` does not copy Views, appsettings.json, or wwwroot to the bin. So, we need to specify `CopyToOutputDirectory` explicitly; and to do that, we also need to set `EnableDefaultContentItems` to false, otherwise our explicit settings will duplicate the default content item settings.

Second, modify Program.cs to specify the new ContentRoot and WebRoot. Out of the box, `Program.cs` sets `UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`. Problematically for our situation, the current directory is the directory *from which we run the executable*. So, if we run the EXE from the command line at our desktop, then the current directory will be `C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop`. The app will not find the Views, appsettings.json, and other content.

Here are some working steps that I have used to meet the challenge as I have interpreted it.

#### Working Steps

1. `cd C:\temp`
2. `dotnet new mvc`
3. Update the temp.csproj with the "Working csproj" XML.
4. Update the Program.cs with the "Working Program.cs" code.
5. `dotnet restore`
6. `dotnet build`
7. `cd ..`
8. From *anywhere*, run `C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\win10-x64\temp.exe`

#### Working csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">                                                    

  <PropertyGroup>                                                                        
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>                                     
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>                                     
    <OutputType>exe</OutputType>                                                         
    <EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>
  </PropertyGroup>                                                                       

  <ItemGroup>                                                                            
     <Content Include="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
     <Content Include="Views\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
     <Content Include="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>                                                                           

  <ItemGroup>                                                                            

     <!-- Package references omitted for clarity -->

  </ItemGroup>                                                                           

</Project>
```

#### Working Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\win10-x64\temp.dll            
        var assemblyFilePath = 
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;

        // C:\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\win10-x64\
        var binDirectory = 
            System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyFilePath);

        Console.WriteLine(assemblyFilePath);
        Console.WriteLine(binDirectory);

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(binDirectory) // <--
            .UseWebRoot("wwwroot") // <--
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already had that one defined and it doesn't work. I tried creating a new project as well. It does not work either (when I add the propertygroup you defined). Can you see my `.csproj` file in the edit.

Comment: that is correct. I again updated my question to outline the error.

Comment: `PreserveCompilationContext` is already set by way of  `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`

Comment: Thank you @ChadT. After further research, I believe I have found an answer. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm no export on MSBuild, but that looks OK. I don't actually agree that there is a problem here from the OP. `Building` and `Publishing` are two discreet steps - this is by design. You don't want to be copying around all your static assets everytime  C# needs to be compiled.

Comment: @ChadT Fair point. The OP is in some ways asking how to shoot his own foot.

Comment: Thank you Shaun it seems to be working. I have added an update to the question, to fix an error I got. Just FYI.

Comment: @ChadT and Shaun. I do understand that this is not how the use is intended. I just found it weird, that earlier we were able to run the compiled code directly from the bin dir. I was using this in my solution to run all our micro services from a small homemade program(to avoid having visual studio open 10 services everytime). The easiest way to do this was to target the location of the bin directory. This is only for development, and when I am moving to production, I do the full publish and use this to populate my NuGet package. Shaun can you elaborate on the shooting myself in the foot part?

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this as an issue to the ASP.NET Core repo on GitHub:
https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2897

While the accepted answer works, it feels a bit like a hack.

There are problems with it too. The build process is slow when there are a lot of files to copy, and the build process does not remove files that have been deleted.

The accepted answer is also a misuse of the EnableDefaultContentItems setting.

So while I'm glad there is a short-term solution, a long-term solution to the problem needs to be sought.

Hopefully, the issue I've raised at GitHub will work someway towards a more permenant solution.