# Cannot find views when running dot net core MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have developed an ASP.NET Core MVC website using Visual Studio for Mac.  When I run the application through the IDE everything works as expected.

After running:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

and then:

```
dotnet my-project-name.dll
```

the application starts as expected, however it does not seem to be able to load any view files:

[image]

The 'Landing' view is stored in /Views/Shared

I've tried adding the following line to my WebHostBuilder:

```
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

This removes the error message from the console, however the home page still does not load.

(NOTE: the 'Landing' view is used by the default endpoint)

All suggestions and questions welcome.
James

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42912165/3324478), It looks like you might be missing the copy to output directory directive in the csproj file. I had what looks like the same problem and adding the following fixed it for me.

`<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
 </ItemGroup>`

I added this "Content" block to an existing "ItemGroup" with other "Content" entries.